# Grab auto Download Links Using requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, download, python-requests

I'm Trying to grab auto started direct download Link from [Yourupload](https://www.yourupload.com/) using Bs4

the direct download Link is auto generated every time,
the direct download Link also start automatically after 5 seconds,
i want to get the direct download Link and store it in "Link.txt" Files

```
import requests
import bs4

req = requests.get('https://www.yourupload.com/download?file=2573285', stream = True)

req = bs4.BeautifulSoup(req.text,'lxml')

print(req)
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal code example.

Comment: @ManaliKagathara the `OP` is already provided a minimal example at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, actually the site is running a `JavaScript` code to handle the redirect to the `final-destination` url to `stream` the download with just `token` validation.

Now we will be more wolfs and get through it.

We will send a `GET` `request` firstly with maintaining the `session` via `requests.Session()` to maintain the `session` object and again send `GET` request to download the `Video` :).

Which means that you currently have the final `url`, you can do whatever, to download it now or later.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def Main():
    main = "https://www.yourupload.com/download?file=2573285"
    with requests.Session() as req:
        r = req.get(main)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
        token = soup.findAll("script")[2].text.split("'")[1][-4:]
        headers = {
            'Referer': main
        }
        r = req.get(
            f"https://www.yourupload.com/download?file=2573285&sendFile=true&token={token}", stream=True, headers=headers)
        print(f"Downloading From {r.url}")
        name = r.headers.get("Content-Disposition").split('"')[1]
        with open(name, 'wb') as f:
            for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024*1024):
                if chunk:
                    f.write(chunk)
            print(f"File {name} Saved.")


Main()
```

Output:

```
Downloading From https://s205.vidcache.net:8166/play/a202003090La0xSot1Kl/okanime-2107-HD-19_99?&attach=okanime-2107-HD-19_99.mp4
File okanime-2107-HD-19_99.mp4 Saved.
```

Confirmation By Size:  As you can see `250M`

[image]

> Notice that the download link is one time callable as the token is only validated one-time by the back-end.